# Searching for a string in a xml field in xslt

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have a set of values like '0100','AD','0200'. I have a xml field ws:String1. I need to check this field for any one of the above 3 values, How do I do that in XSLT?

Thanks Martin. Your code worked, I had to add xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" and it took care of the syntax error. Thanks.

Comment: The String might contain values like 'BIKE 0100', 'HD100', 'Ab_AD', 'DB_0200". So for these values I need to check if  one of the above 3 is found.

Comment: It is not clear how your input data looks, consider to edit your question and insert a minimal but complete XML input sample showing some variants of possible input data to illustrate the problem. In general, assuming your description of "a set of values" in XSLT/XPath 2.0 terms means a sequence of strings e.g. `<xsl:param name="values" as="xs:string*" select="'0100','AD','0200'"/>` then you can check for instance in a predicate `ws:String1[some $value in $values satisfies contains(., $value)]` that e.g. `0100` is contained in e.g. `BIKE 0100`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I have some value in a field ws:string which will contain values like BIKE 0100 or HD100 or Ab_AD. Now I need to check this against values like '0100','AD' etc. My code is

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I tried that. My input data looks like                     <ws:String1>AD Paris (100H)</ws:String1>. Since this contains 'AD' I need to process that record. It says "XPST0081: Namespace prefix 'xs' has not been declared".